# Getting dropped to login-screen

Tags: 13.04, graphics

I'm having a serious problem since I updated to 13.04 recently.

I keep getting dropped to the login-screeen. A bit of googling suggested it's probably coused by something crashing my desktop. What happens is the screen turns black, sometimes there is some code flashing by, and then Im delivered to the loginscreen. When I login, all programs are turned off, and more often than not, hours of work are lost.

The code flashing by is different from time to time, But I've noticed sometimes the words "checking battery status". (So far, every time this has happened, the charger has been plugged in) I'm inclined to think this might have some connection to the whole

Every time I log in again after this happens, I get the "Ubuntu has experienced an internal error" dialog, and of course I report it. But this is getting out of hand, *I need help, Quick*!

Seems to occur at completely random occations, applications running last time it occured was: Firefox, Chromium, and Tilda(a drop down terminal application which I've set to run at startup)

I considered posting my entire .xsession-errors file here, thinking it might help shed some light on what's causing this but it's quite a lot of text, anything I should be looking for in there? Any part of it that would be more interesting than the rest(beginning/end) ?

Thanks a lot for any help at all, this is driving me crazy!

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 **AMD64** (64-bit) ? Do you have **Intel** graphics (or Nvidia, etc.) ?

Comment: Open the 'details' for internal error. It is **npconfig** related?

Comment: Just a note: I have this problems sometimes as well. I have an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4650. The problem also happens in Windows and causes explorer to crash. This has lead me to believe that my video card has a faulty memory segment. The only solution: change you video card if you can or get a new motherboard (in my case, laptop). Of course, this is my specific problem, though it does have some things in common with yours.

Comment: **@Githlar**: I'm getting same issue (**npconfig**,  *internal errors*). It is **NOT** specific to one PC, and also occurs on fresh install of **13.04 64-bit** on another computer. (IMHO recent updates, not hardware memory, related)

Comment: @david6: I use AMD Radeon graphics. Will check out the details next time it happens and post them here! fortunatly I've been going a few days without getting dropped now, I'm almost starting to hope the issue has been solved through some update I've made...